# I want to run a command until I let go of the key

Tags: python, curses

I have coded some motors on an RC car and copied some code which uses the curses module. At the moment when I control the car it runs the same command such as forwards or left until I give it another such as right. I want it to stop moving when I release the key. How would I do that?

```
try:
shell = curses.initscr()
shell.nodelay(False)
curses.noecho()


while True:
    key = shell.getch()
    
    if key ==  65:
        right()
        time.sleep(0.1)
```

That's the code I've been using so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The way you describe it you are looking for a way to determine "no key pressed".
As [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html#curses.window.getch), getch returns -1 in "no delay mode", i.e. setting [shell.nodelay()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html#curses.window.nodelay) to True.

Afterwards, you can assign the "-1" case to a stopping command (whatever that is in your case).

```
shell = curses.initscr()
shell.nodelay(True)  # <- make getch non-blocking
curses.noecho()


while True:
    key = shell.getch()
    
    if key == -1:  # <- no key pressed
        stop()  # <- appropriate stop functionality
        time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: That works amazingly! But It takes about a second for it to stop running once I've stopped pressing the key. I am trying to get it to be instant or is that not possible?

Comment: That depends on how your "move" and "stop" functions are constructed. By your description it sounds like either the move or the stop function have a "reaction time" of 1 second. Is there a documentation of the used RC Car API? Maybe this would clarify this behaviour.

Comment: Oh, and (obviously) removing the time.sleep() calls should increase the responsiveness as well. But it sounds like you are looking for more that 0.1 seconds.

Comment: https://github.com/CamJam-EduKit/EduKit3/blob/50706a443e49b8d2363dac56bc8f97e16e2692e6/CamJam%20Edukit%203%20-%20RPi.GPIO/Code/10-cli.py   this is the code i've been using

Comment: I cannot see an obvious reason for delays > 0.1 seconds in this code. You could put a bunch of performance measurements into each section to see where he spends his time. Mini-Example: import time; t_start=time.perf_counter(); stop_motors(); print(f"stop_motors took {time.perfcounter()-t_start:.1f} seconds.")